# Using unplaced annotation without editing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation

I'm working with a layer that isn't editable, and when attempting to convert labels to annotation, there were some unplaced annotations. 
In the past, I would just open the unplaced annotation window and add them. I have discovered that in 10.0, the annotation has been moved into the editing environment. 
Since I can't edit the layer, I can't access the unplaced annotation. by the same token, I can't create database stored annotation since the destination is not an editable environment, and can't be changed.
Apart from exporting the layer in question into an editable location, is there a workaround for map-stored annotation that can be accessed outside of an edit session?

Comment: Can you upgrade to at least 10.1?  There are major fixes and improvements over 10.0.  This may be one of them.  I have no problems with annotation and I'm using 10.3.  I can create annotations and access unplaced annotations.

Comment: At home, I have 10.4 and no issue, but at work the upgrade is being held off pending a major upgrade that's already a month overdue.

Comment: In the meantime, you could store your labels as a point file..